# Fixing the code directly in the question

Tags: discussion

There is a question:
[exchange two words using sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70600/exchange-two-words-using-sed)

Two people tried to fix the code directly in the question. Then question edit was blocked.

Can somebody explain me why the code was changed directly in the question and furtermore the question now is blocked?

How can we help somebody and explain his mistakes or typos, when other people change the original code to make question completely unclear without any explanation for OP and others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're reading something wrong. The only code change was indenting the block so it shows up as code instead of text:

http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-70600-diff.png

The code might've looked different, because slashes escape things in normal markdown, but not in code. For example, `\(` shows up as just ( in normal text, but in code it's:

```
\(
```

As for "Then question edit was blocked", I'm not sure what you're talking about; the question is still unlocked and anybody can edit it. One of the revision comments was ["block"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/70600/4), but I think he meant "making a code block"

Comment: ah, ok. it looks like my misunderstood. thanks for clarification.